# C# and pointer to member

Tags: c#, c++, pointer-to-member

Need to call function for an object of certain type, but i want the caller to specify function i call.

In C++ i can use pointer to member like this

```
class C 
{
    void F(void (A::*F)(int));
}
```

Is there any C# equivalent?

No arrays of function or any tricks like switches please. I want this solution to work even if new function added while function signature meets the requirements.

EDIT:
As i have read: *Delegates are like C++ function pointers but are type safe.*

But i need member function pointer. E.g. in my function i acquire certaint object:

```
var properties = manager.GetProperties();
```

and now need to get certain type of properties:

```
var type1 = properties.GetType1();
```

but i need something like this

```
var typeX = properties.GetTypeX();
```

to get user requested type for this function call. What TypeX must be?

Where Type1..N have common base class, and i need to work with this class.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes C# has Delegates - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Are `Type1` and `TypeX` meant to be [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)? Or are you missing the `()` on your methods. If you define the getter and setter of a property you can return whatever you want - but it has nothing to do with delegates..

Comment: what is the problem that you are trying to resolve here? Are you stating that the caller should define what type to return? If you do `GetTypeX()`, what should happen? should a value from `properties` that the caller decides be returned? Why not have properties (like I mentioned in the earlier comment) for the values that you want to expose? What issue is it that you are trying to resolve here with a function pointer?

Comment: Are you referring to [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx) or [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)? I still don't understand your issue.

Comment: @Default properties have different names, but return objects with the same base class.

Comment: but that has nothing to do with method pointers or delegates, it has to do with `polymorphism`! Can you rephrase your question to not include those keywords and instead try to explain your problem?

Comment: @Default i need exactly pointer to member! Which polymorphysm if functions have different names?

Comment: if `GetType1()` and `GetTypeX()` should return a *common base class*, as you have described, that, IMHO only relates to polymorphism. I fail to see what the benefit of function pointers is here.

Comment: @Default, plymorphysm are NOT available if functions have different names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

There are two standard ones: [`Func<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

Comment: A delegate is not the same as a pointer to member - primarily, a delegate can't be constrained (and the delegate equivalent to point to member would be `Func<T,TMember>`.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there are [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify signature of function which you want to pass somewhere.

Your code should try something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Write(int i)
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C { FunctionToExecute = Write };
        c.SomeMethod(5);
    }
}

delegate void D(int F);

class C
{
    public D FunctionToExecute { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod(int arg)
    {
        FunctionToExecute(arg);
    }
}
```

D specifies signature, FunctionToExecute is pointer to what you want to execute.

If you want to pass objects of unknown types then there are [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx). Or I don't understand exactly what do you want. Mentioned here Action and Func are generic delegates.

Comment: Please, in this day & age, do not advise people to define their own delegates. Use Action<int> instead of your `D` delegate.

Comment: Yes, in particular cases there are Action and Func predefined delegates. I just didn't understand all the C++ syntaxys, so I wrote the most general case :) To be honest - never created my own delegate types.

Comment: @DavidArno: Really? Delegates are just another type - it's not unusual at all.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas When we have Func<> and Action<>, there is no need to reinvent the wheel by defining new delegate types.